# How to get data by associative order?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two tables.

1. chat_rooms
2. chat_pinned_rooms

**chat_rooms** has `has_many` relation with **chat_pinned_rooms** by `chat_room_id`.

Now I want to sort (order) `chat_rooms` data by `chat_pinned_rooms`.

I have tried below queries :

```php
$this->ChatRooms->find()
    ->contain('ChatPinnedRooms', function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->id])
            ;
        })
    ->order([
        'ChatRooms.ChatPinnedRooms.id' => 'ASC'
    ])
    ->all()
;
```

If I use this order in contain, it will just sort the data in those associations. But I need to sort the parent table data (`chat_rooms`) by associative order.

Comment: You have a logic problem to solve first! You have a `1:n` association, there can be many pinned rooms per chat room, so by which of those many pinned room row's `id` column would you want to sort and why? Try to figure first how you would solve your problem with raw SQL, it's usually easier to then go from there and translate things to the query builder.

Comment: @ndm 
Actually, I want to have the chatroom which has pinned in the top , and the ones which is not pinned in the bottom. 

So, if I have ten chat_rooms, and two of them pinned. I want to display those two pinned chat_rooms in the top.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand that correctly, you want to sort those `ChatRooms` first who do have 1 or more associated `ChatPinnedRooms`?

Comment: @ndm Yes ! you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort those `ChatRooms` first who do have 1 or more associated `ChatPinnedRooms`, then you could either join in the `ChatPinnedRooms` association, create groups per `ChatRooms.id`, and sort based on for example the count of `ChatPinnedRooms` in those groups, something along the lines of this:

```php
$query = $this->ChatRooms
    ->find()
    ->leftJoinWith('ChatPinnedRooms', function ($q) {
        return $q
            ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->id]);
    })
    ->group('ChatRooms.id')
    ->orderAsc(function (
        \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
        \Cake\ORM\Query $q
    ) {
        return $exp->gte(
            $q->func()->count('ChatPinnedRooms.id'),
            1
        );
    });
```

```sql
LEFT JOIN ... ChatPinnedRooms ...
GROUP BY ChatRooms.id
ORDER BY COUNT(ChatPinnedRooms.id) >= 1 ASC
```

(if you want to include the pinned rooms in the results, you'd need to `contain()` them too, just like in your example) or you could use counter caching, so that you have a concrete column in `ChatRooms` that holds the count of associated records, which you can then use for sorting, like:

```php
// in `ChatPinnedRoomsTable` class
$this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
    'ChatRooms' => ['chat_pinned_rooms_count'],
]);
```

```php
$query = $this->ChatRooms
    ->find()
    ->order([
        'chat_pinned_rooms_count >=' => 1,
    ]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using leftJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Ordering Results](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#ordering-results)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > CounterCache](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)**